# Why does mongoid not persist sometimes?

Tags: mongoid

I have a mongoid object that for some reason doesn't persist...

```
# @wallet.currency is 1
@wallet.currency = 5
@wallet.save # => true
@wallet.reload
@wallet.currency # => 1
```

I can work around this issue:

```
Wallet.where( :id => @wallet.id ).update_all( :currency => 5 ) # this saves
```

but I would really like to understand why a *.save in mongoid doesn't work sometimes? This will help me a lot to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: there are few qestions. which mongoid version you are using? when you say not persisted do you mean not saved in DB or not reloaded in shell with object.reload ?

Comment: not saved to mongodb (i'm verifying with mongo shell). The version is 3.2.10

Comment: Do you have any callbacks that affect `currency` before getting saved? May be you can try removing all those.